# Set last level as reference category for all regression analyses

Tags: r, regression

By default R sets the *first* level of a factor variable as the reference category in regression.  I know how to use relevel to specify another level, but I'm wondering if there is a setting or something so I can globally force R to set the *last* level of factors as the reference category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since that is the SAS default, there ist a wrapper for `contr.treatment` that sets the last level as reference level:

```
options(contrasts = c(unordered = "contr.SAS", ordered = "contr.poly"))
fit <-lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
coef(fit)
#(Intercept)     Speciessetosa Speciesversicolor 
#      6.588            -1.582            -0.652 
levels(iris$Species)
#[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Comment: Thanks, Roland.  This is great!  In fact, I'm comparing some SAS genmod results with geepack and gee and this will come in very handy!  I have another post forthcoming about a discrepancy between the two now that I can compare the two procedures.